# Inductor through hole legs different length

Tags: inductor

Why would the legs on a radial through hole inductor be different lengths from eash other?  There is no polarity to indicate like a LED or Electrolytic cap...

Comment: Are they different lengths? Most of the ones I've seen are the same length.

Comment: A specific example will help... ok found one: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2360322.pdf?_ga=2.58097123.878658233.1556312382-1788324274.1556312382

Comment: There will be some difference in the external field, for example.

Comment: Easier to insert into a pcb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the properties are a bit different depending on mounting direction. From the murata website (https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/emiconfun/inductor/2012/05/14/en-20120514-p1):

> If the inductor structure is not perfectly symmetric, properties will
>   change with the mounting direction. We therefore leave a mark so that
>   the user will know the inductor has directionality. That way, when
>   they use the inductor, they can hope to make the fullest use of the
>   intended properties.

---

Also it can be useful to know the polarity to understand the direction of the magnetic field that will be induced. If a lot of inductors are used close to each other, their fields will interact.

Comment: The link is for surface mount which I can understand, but this is a radial through hole bobbin.

Comment: What is "this" which you are referring too.  Please be so kind as to post a link to the datasheet, or at least a picture.  Until then, -1 to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the long leg indicates the bottom of the vertical coil.  When I placed them in a Hartley oscillator the legs had to both be in the same orientation for it to work.  Something new for me so lesson learned and filed for future use.